# Some context menus are really slow

Tags: windows, context-menu

When I right-click on some areas the context menu is really slow to appear.

It happens on the Desktop, Explorer, Chrome and Visual Studio but not on ShellExView, Device Manager, Regedit.

I tried :

- Disabling all the Extensions via ShellExView
- Look at the registry to find an entry for NVidia/Intel/ATI, there were none.
- Checked for Windows updates
- Disabled Chrome Extensions

Nothing worked

Edit : Just realized that when I reboot, it's ok for the first few seconds.

Comment: Monitor in task manager.. the process and services. After a restart. You will find some program which is consumption high memory and process.. do you use any software CVS or svn clients??

Comment: I had checked the performance tab which didn't budge. I checked process and services but nothing. I have git for Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to uninstall a couple of apps without success. I ended up resetting Windows. Now it works...